# window.unload in IE8

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to execute a JavaScript on `unload` of a child window which was opened by the parent window. I tried the below code and it is not calling the function.

```
 childWindow = window.open(url, 'MyWindow', GetWindowOptions(1020, 600), true);
 childWindow.onunload = function () { test(); };
```

And the test function which I wrote is:

```
function test() {
alert(1);
}
```

I am using IE8 browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `attachEvent` instead of the `onunload` setter to add the event. I've tested it in IE6 - 8, and it works fine. Make sure that you also use `addEventListener` for IE9+ and other browsers:

```
var unloadFunc = function () { test(); };
if (childWindow) { // null if a pop-up blocker does not create the window
    if (childWindow.addEventListener) {
        childWindow.addEventListener('unload', unloadFunc, false);
    } else {
        childWindow.attachEvent('onunload', unloadFunc);
    }
}
```

Obviously, this will not work if the URL is from a different domain.
If you want to execute a function when a window from a **different origin** is closed, use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to poll for the value of the boolean property `childWindow.closed`. It's true when the window has been closed.

For example:

```
if (childWindow) { // null if a pop-up blocker does not create the window
    setTimeout(function checkState() {
        if (childWindow.closed) {
            // onunload Logic here.
        } else {
            setTimeout(checkState, 250);
        }
    }, 250);
}
```

---

Note: Other answers suggested to use the `beforeunload` event. Keep in mind that the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/history.html#unloading-documents) allows implementations to ignore `confirm`, `alert`, `prompt` and `showModalDialog` calls during this event.

Comment: Worked.. Thanks!!! But can you explain me why my code isn't working... i just added a simple unload event to the window which i created.

Comment: @RutwikReddy IE ignored the setter.

Comment: Thanks alot buddy. You'r a Genius. The best solution i found so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something with `onbeforeunload`. I use something like this on a print report for a intranet app that do an AJAX call to mark it was printed:

```
if (window.onbeforeunload) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { didPrint(someData); };
} else {
    window.onunload = function() { didPrint(someData); };
}
```

Comment: I gave it a try... but no luck :(

Comment: Are you having any errors? Try pressing F12 and go to the script tab and press start debugging.